# Solve multiple equations with a parameter by means of Reduce

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I have developed a program that solves an equation and give its solutions as outputs:

```
m = 0.3
n = -0.9
equation = Reduce[E^(m*x) + E^(n* x) == x, x, Reals]
sol1 = N[x /. ToRules[equation[[1]]]]
sol2 = N[x /. ToRules[equation[[2]]]]
```

whose answers are approximately 1.97121 and 5.93163. However, I need `m` to change and, therefore, to render a different solution each time I change it. So I need `m` to be also 0.05, 0.06, 0.1,… and whatever numbers I define in a list. How can I arrange `Reduce` to read the different values and to solve the equation for each of them, given a list of values for `m`?

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

n = -9/10;

sol[m_?NumericQ] := NSolve[{E^(m*x) + E^(n*x) == x, x > 0}, x, Reals]

sol[0.3]

(* {{x -> 1.97921}, {x -> 5.93163}} *)

data = Select[Table[{m, x /. sol[m]}, {m, 0.01, 0.5, 0.01}], 
   UnsameQ[#[[2]], x] &];

ListLogPlot[data[[All, 2]] // Transpose,
 DataRange -> MinMax[data[[All, 1]]],
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Using bisection to find where the curves intersect:

```
lb = 0.35`20; ub = 0.36`20;

While[ub - lb > 10^-12,
 a = (lb + ub)/2;
 If[sol[a] === {}, ub = a, lb = a]]

{lb, sol[lb]} // N

(* {0.358662, {{x -> 3.01982}, {x -> 3.01982}}} *)
```

Comment: Absolutely FLAWLESS, dear Bob. Thank you for your support. You’re what I would call a ‘fluent speaker’ of Mathematica, even a native one, ha ha: those were some fancy Mathematica functions I didn’t know they existed, like `NumericQ`. I still have lots to learn.

I still cannot cast my vote since my reputation ask for a couple of more points, but people seeing this comment may know this code works appropriately without a shadow of a doubt.